# How to use the constraints created from iOS 9 in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

How to use the constraints created from iOS 9 in Objective C?
In Swift this shall be like this:

```
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

Comment: Is the code snippet works? what's the problem? :)

Comment: I want this to work in objc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you simply asking for an Objective-C translation of your Swift code?

```
[button.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.centreYAnchor].active = YES;
[button.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = YES;
```

The constraints behave and are used in exactly the same way, regardless of the language you use to create them.

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly this.